# Auto generated voice call in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, ivr

I have database value with name,mobile number and individual message. I need to send a voice call to all entries once.

I'm using SmartIVR for the voice calls but i need to how to pass voice information to SmartIVR, because they'll support only voice files not text to voice.

Comment: You can convert text to speech/voice file (There are many libraries available) and send using voice call api

Comment: can you elaborate or suggest a library which is suits best for codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use TextToSpeech you can use Voximal with the Dialer (free/opensource based on GnuDialer).
When you insert the call, you can add a paramter in the param field.
This value will be accessible in the VoiceXML session context with the variable:

```
telephone.param
```

You will be able to use it with a prompt form example :

```
<prompt>Dear <value expr="telephone.param"/>, how are you ?</prompt>
```